# i want to run tcp within a uwp application but without blocking the main thread

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, tcp, hololens

hi now i am currently working on grabbing the frames of the camera of the hololens 2 then send those frames through a TCP protocol ....... the application has a UI xaml file and I want to run the TCP by clicking a button in this UI xaml but when I do it looks like grabbing the frames stops so I think the problem here is that I am running the TCP and sending the frames in the same UI thread where I also run grabbing the and displaying the frames

the question is how to run the TCP in a parallel way where it works without affecting grabbing the frames I am using c# and c++ ..... c# to grab the frames and c++ opencv to convert the frames into mat file and also to creat the TCP and send the mat file over the network

Answer (score 0):

You need two threads, one mutex and a queue.

**Thread A** (pseudo code)

```
while (true) {
    //allocate memory for the frame
    frame = alloc_frame();
    //capture frame into allocated memory
    grab(frame);
    //enter critical section
    lock_mutex();
        //add the frame to the end of the queue
        queue_push(frame);
    //leave critical section
    unlock_mutex();
}
```

**Thread B** (pseudo code)

```
while (true) {
    //enter critical section
    lock_mutex();
        //remove the oldest frame from the queue
        frame = queue_pop();
    //leave critical section
    unlock_mutex();
    //process the frame
    process(frame);
    //send the frame through your tcp connection
    send(frame);
    //release the frame, 
    //either give it back to a memory pool (reusage) or 
    //delete the block of memory
    release(frame);
}
```

The bottlenecks here are allocating the frame and locking the mutex. But if you use a memory pool, the allocating shouldn't be of concern. The time to aquire a lock, shouldn't be of a great concern either, since only two threads are involved. So, the capture thread spends the most time in grabbing the frame.

The main issue is: in case of a slow connection the queue will grow in time. A threshold can help to prevent memory exhaustion. In that case, you have to skip frames or pause the grabbing.